# Void CheckError Oracle x IIS

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, iis

Bom, devido ao esgotamento das minhas tentativas de encontrar o erro, vou tentar buscar uma luz aqui com vocês. Desde já peço desculpas se o erro for genérico demais e não tiver as infos necessárias.

Mas ai vai uma parte do cenário e a situação:

SITUAÇÃO: A aplicação rodando no ISS em homologação ou produção, sendo usada por vários usuários, em um dado momento cai, em qualquer parte da aplicação. Isso ocorre ao acessar algum método ou mudar de página. É nessário reiniciar o IIS para a aplicação voltar a funcionar. Erro disparado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho impressão que essa informação é muito genérica. O método no qual se dá o erro é um metodo de obtenção de usuário. Método esse que é disparado em toda mudança de página. Pode acontecer em outros métodos de acesso ao banco também. Por isso não colocarei código a principio.

OBS: Rodando a aplicação na própria máquina no visual studio não acontece erro nenhum, em nenhum momento.

Tendo em vista que o erro só se da quando está rodando no IIS, eu gostaria de saber o que pode estar causando isso. Se é alguma configuração do IIS, ou se pode ser algum problema de gerenciamento das conexões com o oracle que reiniciando o IIS ele limpa e ai volta a funfar.

Estou aberto a fazer edições incluindo informações de acordo com as sugestões e qualquer dica de caminho a se investigar será bem vinda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela breve descrição, o problema parece que está acontecendo por causa das configurações de reciclagem do pool de aplicação do seu site/aplicação no IIS.

Reveja as configurações de reciclagem, talvez o seu problema seja resolvido.

Um link para saber mais sobre [reciclagem do pool no IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179(v=ws.10).aspx).